# How to build two wave different phase same frequency using AD9850 and Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, labview

I want to build a dual signal wave in different phase to bridge amplifier form dual dds signal generator ad9850.

I have code to build a single wave but no idea how to build two wave different phase using Arduino and be able to control it via VISA SPI LabVIEW interface.

Arduino & AD9850 Dual DDS Signal Generator:

```cpp
#define W_CLK 8  // Pin 8 - connect to AD9850 module word Load clock pin (CLK)
#define FQ_UD 9  // Pin 9 - connect to freq update pin (FQ)
#define DATA 10  // Pin 10 - connect to serial data Load pin (DATA)
#define RESET 11 // Pin 11 - connect to reset pin (RST).
#define pulseHigh(pin) {digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); 

digitalWrite(pin, LOW); }

// transfers a byte, a bit at a time, LSB first to the 9850 via serial DATA Line
void tfr_byte(byte data) {
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++, data >>= l) {
    digitalWrite (DATA, data & 0x01);
    pulseHigh(W_CLK); //after each bit sent, CLK is pulsed high
  }
}
    
// frequency calc from datasheet page 8 = <sys clock> * <frequency tuning word>/2^32
void sendFrequency(double frequency) {
  int32_t freq = frequency * 4294967295/125000000; // note 125 MHz clock on 9850
  for (int b=0 ; b<4 ; b++, freq >>= 8) {
    tfr_byte(freq & 0xFF );
  }
  tfr_byte(0x00); // Final control byte, all 0 for 9850 chip
  pulseHigh(FQ_UD); // Done! Should see output
}
    
void setup() {
  // configure arduino data pins for output
  pinMode (FQ_UD, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (W_CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (DATA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (RESET, OUTPUT);
  
  pulseHigh(RESET);
  pulseHigh(W_CLK);
  pulseHigh(FQ_UD); // this pulse enables serial mode - Datasheet page 12 figure 10
}

void loop() {
  sendFrequency(10.e6); // freq
  while (l);
}
```

Any idea to build a second wave using Arduino and controlling it with LabVIEW?

My block diagram LabVIEW:

[image]

My front panel LabVIEW:

[image]

Comment: break your problem down into atomic subproblems. is your problem on the Arduino or the LabView side? if so remove the non-problematic part from your question. focus! any own ideas? the datasheet lists only two analogue outputs where the second one is the complementary of the first one. what makes you think you can output two phase shifted signals?

Comment: The solution is in the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks Piglet and Michael, but in the data sheet there is no explanation for making two waves with different phases